# AndroidManifest.xml user defined data - is it possible?

Tags: android, android-manifest, user-defined

I'm thinking about possibility to put into AndroidManifest.xml some custom data. E.g. version of SQLite database for this particular release of app.

For sure i can put those data as hardcoded in sources or somewhere in preferences, but still I'm just wondering is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put it in a res/values xml file (maybe res/values/strings.xml) as a constant?

Comment: From the docs it doesn't look like it would be possible within the Manifest. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html